# A dash or ellipsis when someone doesn't finish their sentence?

Tags: punctuation

The speaker, in their stupefaction, leaves the sentence trail off. Would it be:

What on earth...?!

Or:

What on earth--?!

Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An ellipsis is more appropriate.  According to GrammarBook.com, an ellipsis is used when omitting a word or phrase, whereas a dash is more appropriate for adding emphasis or an interruption in the current chain of thought/speech.

More on ellipses:
http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/ellipses.asp

More on dashes:
http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/dashes.asp